# Проблема с размещением данных в С++

Tags: память, visual-studio, c++

Доброго времени суток! Прошу помочь мне со следующей проблемой:

У меня описаны константы:

```
  const int N=256;  // кол-во пикселей в изображении (размер входного вектора x).
  const int K=160;  // кол-во нейронов скрытого слоя.
```

И есть класс **NeuronHidden**

```
 class NeuronHidden             // Нейрон скрытого слоя
 {
  private:
     double w[N];     // веса синапсов входного вектора x
  public:
         Остальной код (4 небольших метода);
  };
```

И еще один класс **NeuronNet**

```
 class NeuronNet
 {
 private:
      NeuronHidden NH[K];   // Нейроны скрытого слоя
      Остальной код;
 };
```

При указанных константах, все компилируется и отлично работает.

Но мне необходимо **N=2704** и **K=1352**, а при таких значениях программа компилируется, но при попытке создать экземпляр объекта выдает ошибку

***"Необработанное исключение в "0x0041d367" в "NeuronNet1.exe": 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow."***

и студия выдает файл с асемблерным кодом:

```
; Find next lower page and probe
cs20:
    sub     eax, _PAGESIZE_         ; decrease by PAGESIZE
    test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page.
    jmp     short cs10

_chkstk endp
```

где подчеркивает строку **test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page.**

Как я понял стек переполняется, а что с этим можно сделать? Как увеличить размер стека? Пишу в Visual Studio C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делай массив в куче

```
double * w;
```

В конструкторе

```
w = new double [N];
```

В деструкторе

```
delete [] w;
```

Comment: Утечет в случае исключения в конструкторе.

Comment: Я нарисовал лишь общую схему. Надо еще писать копирующий конструктор, operator= и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

1. Увеличить размер стека, но..
2. лучше размещать объекты в куче, например, с помощью контейнера std::vector. Тогда сможете делать нейронную сеть любого масштаба.

Answer (score 2):

Приведённый тобой код можно вообще не менять. Экземпляры NeuronNet нужно создавать в динамической памяти, а не на стеке. То есть

```
NeuronNet* net=new NeuronNet;
//...Не забыть удалить через delete
```

а не

```
NeuronNet net;
```

Таким образом, ты создашь всю нейронную сеть в одном большом блоке памяти. Это работает быстрее, чем создание тысяч маленьких массивов, как тебе предложили.

Comment: 1.Для большого блока памяти требуется один большой непрерывный диапазон виртуальных адресов, что и хорошо, если такой блок создается один раз вначале работы программы, но и плохо, если приходится делать это многократно и несколько раз.
2. Т.к. данные в блоке содержатся разноразмерные, то, скорее всего, возникнут проблемы с выравниваем, что скажется на производительности.

Comment: А зачем? Насчет быстрее - очень сомнительно

Предолженый мною вариант, думаю, придаст гибкость системе. Можно объект размещать где угодно.

Comment: >Для большого блока памяти требуется один большой непрерывный диапазон виртуальных адресов, что и хорошо, если такой блок создается один раз вначале работы программы, но и плохо, если приходится делать это многократно и несколько раз.

 В его случае это около 30 МБ. Разве это так много?

>Т.к. данные в блоке содержатся разноразмерные, то, скорее всего, возникнут проблемы с выравниваем, что скажется на производительности.

 Какие проблемы с выравниванием, если у него одни double?

>А зачем? Насчет быстрее - очень сомнительно

 Быстрее само выделение. Само использование не ускорится.

Comment: Всем спасибо! За идею, я просто не придумал ничего умнее чем -увеличить стек. Когда сделал через указатели на объекты нейронов, то N можно было увеличить уже до 2000 тысяч, а потом опять ошибка. Решил запихнуть в кучу всю сеть, все равно ведь она создается один раз при запуске программы, стало возможным задавать любое N. Зашел сюда и собственно это и прочитал, только я не удалял. А что будет если не удалить? В оперативной памяти будет валяться занятый кусок, который сотрется при выключении питания?

Comment: >А что будет если не удалить? В оперативной памяти будет валяться занятый кусок, который сотрется при выключении питания?

 При выходе из программы вся память процесса по-любому освобождается, но если у объекта есть деструкторы, они не вызовутся без delete. Но всё-равно считается плохим тоном программирования не освобождать ненужную память.